# k-fold cross validation in RankLib

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I want to do 5 fold cross validation on MQ2008 dataset. I am using RankLib to apply ML algo on the dataset. I am confused about the kcv option given in Ranklib for cross validation.
command used:

```
java - jar RankLib.jar -ranker 0 -train train.txt -test test.txt -validate vali.txt -kcv 5
```

here we are specifying different files for training,testing and validation.Then how it is dividing data for 5 fold cross validation.

Answer (score 0):

To do k-fold cross-validation using ranklib, you **only** need to use **one dataset**.

The program itself divides the data to train, test and validate randomly.
When you use 5-fold cross-validation, the program will repeat the process 5 times and it gives you the average of the 5 analyses as the final result.
You need to choose a metric for your learning evaluation. See `[ -metric2t <metric> ]` on this [How to use page](https://sourceforge.net/p/lemur/wiki/RankLib%20How%20to%20use/).

For example, see the command below. I have only one dataset to feed my algorithm. I used `NDCG@10` as my evaluation metric. Also, I used `-kcvmd` to save my models in a directory and `-kcvmn` to name the models.

```
java -jar RankLib-2.1-patched.jar -train trainingData.txt -ranker 8 -kcv 5 -kcvmd kcvModels/ -kcvmn txt -metric2t NDCG@10 -metric2T NDCG@10 -save Models/model.txt
```